# Partial differential equation with initial condition for time derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I am trying to solve the PDE

\begin{align}
u_{tt} - u_{xx} + 2u &= 0
\end{align}

where  $0 \leq x \leq \pi, \ t \geq 0$. The initial conditions are

$$u(x,0) = 0, \quad u_t(x,0)  = \frac{x}{\pi}$$

and the boundary conditions are

$$ u_x(0,t) = 0, \quad u_x(\pi,t) = 0$$

I am trying to solve using separation of variables. Making the ansatz

$$u(x,t) = F(x)G(t)$$

after substitution I get

$$\frac{F''(x)-2F(x)}{F(x)} = \frac{\ddot{G}(t)}{G(t)}=-n^2-2$$

I get finally a solution of the form

$$ u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \cos(nx) \sin(\sqrt{n^2+2}t)  $$

Now I still have to comply with the initial condition for the time derivative

$$u_t(x,0)  = \frac{x}{\pi}$$

This implies

$$ u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \cos(nx) \sqrt{n^2+2} = \frac{x}{\pi}  $$

But $x/\pi$ is an odd function, so it can not be represented by a sum of cosine functions. What did I do wrong?

Comment: How did you get a cosine for the spatial eigenfunction? Dirichlet boundary conditions implies $F(x) = \sin(nx)$. From your series solution, you can check yourself that $$u(0,t) = \sum A_{n} \cdot 1 \cdot \sin(\sqrt{n^{2} + 2t}) \ne 0$$ and similarly for $u(\pi, t)$.

Comment: I made a typo in the boundary conditions. I corrected it in the mean time. As you see the partial derivatives to $x$ should be 0. That is why I have a cosine. Still the same problem...

Comment: You have a half range series, not a full range (i.e $x \in [0, \pi]$ not $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$), hence the cosine series for an odd function exists.

Comment: Of course, $A_n = \frac{2}{\pi}   \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(nx) \frac{x}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}} {\mathrm{d}x} $ . Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\mbox{Lets}\ \mrm{u}_{x}\pars{x,t} =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_{n}\pars{t}\sin\pars{nx}\
\mbox{which already satisfies}\
\mrm{u}_{x}\pars{0,t} = \mrm{u}_{x}\pars{\pi,t} = 0.
\\[5mm] &\
\mbox{Then,}\
\mrm{u}\pars{x,t} =
-\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_{n}\pars{t}\,{\cos\pars{nx} \over n} + \mrm{f}\pars{t}.
\\ &\ \mrm{f}\pars{t}\ \mbox{is a time dependent }\ arbitrary\ \mbox{function ( for the time being ).}
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\mrm{u}\pars{x,t}}$ must satisfy the differential equation. Namely,
\begin{align}
&0 = \bracks{-\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\ddot{a}_{n}\pars{t}\,{\cos\pars{nx} \over n} + \ddot{\mrm{f}}\pars{t}} -
\bracks{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_{n}\pars{t}n\cos\pars{nx}}
\\[5mm] &\ +
2\bracks{-\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_{n}\pars{t}\,{\cos\pars{nx} \over n} + \mrm{f}\pars{t}}
\end{align}
Integrating both sides over $\ds{\pars{0,\pi}} \implies
\ddot{\mrm{f}}\pars{t} + 2\,\mrm{f}\pars{t} = 0 \implies
\mrm{f}\pars{t} = A\sin\pars{\root{2}t} + B\cos\pars{\root{2}t}$.
$\ds{A\ \mbox{and}\ B}$ are constants.

Similarly, integrate after multiplying both sides for a factor
$\ds{\cos\pars{nx}}$ to get
\begin{align}
&\ddot{a}_{n}\pars{t} + \pars{n^{2} + 2}a_{n}\pars{t} = 0
\\ &\ \implies
a_{n}\pars{t} =
a_{n}\pars{0}\cos\pars{\root{n^{2} + 2}t} +
\dot{a}_{n}\pars{0}\,{\sin\pars{\root{n^{2} + 2}t} \over \root{n^{2} + 2}}
\end{align}
The general solution becomes:
\begin{align}
\mrm{u}\pars{x,t} & =
-\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{a_{n}\pars{0}\cos\pars{\root{n^{2} + 2}t} +
\dot{a}_{n}\pars{0}\,{\sin\pars{\root{n^{2} + 2}t} \over \root{n^{2} + 2}}}\,{\cos\pars{nx} \over n}
\\ & +
A\sin\pars{\root{2}t} + B\cos\pars{\root{2}t}
\end{align}
Also,
$$
0 = \mrm{u}\pars{x,0} =
-\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_{n}\pars{0}\,{\cos\pars{nx} \over n} + B
\implies a_{n}\pars{0} = B = 0
$$
The general solution is reduced to
\begin{align}
\mrm{u}\pars{x,t} & =
-\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\dot{a}_{n}\pars{0}\,{\sin\pars{\root{n^{2} + 2}t} \over \root{n^{2} + 2}}\,{\cos\pars{nx} \over n}
+
A\sin\pars{\root{2}t}
\end{align}
In addition,
\begin{align}
\mrm{u}_{t}\pars{x,0} & = {x \over \pi} =
-\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\dot{a}_{n}\pars{0}\,{\cos\pars{nx} \over n}
+
\root{2}A
\end{align}
Integrating both sides over $\ds{\pars{0,\pi} \implies
{\pi \over 2} = \root{2}A\pi \implies A = {\root{2} \over 4}}$. Also,
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\pi}{x \over \pi}\,\cos\pars{nx}\,\dd x =
-\,{\pi \over 2n}\dot{a}_{n}\pars{0} \implies
{\pars{-1}^{n} - 1 \over n^{2}\pi} = -\,{\pi \over 2n}\dot{a}_{n}\pars{0}
\\[5mm] &\
\implies \dot{a}_{n}\pars{0} =
{2 \over \pi^{2}}\,{1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over n}
\end{align}
Finally,
\begin{align}
\mrm{u}\pars{x,t} & =
-\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{2 \over \pi^{2}}\,{1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over n}\,{\sin\pars{\root{n^{2} + 2}t} \over \root{n^{2} + 2}}\,{\cos\pars{nx} \over n}
+
{\root{2} \over 4}\,\sin\pars{\root{2}t}
\\[5mm] & =
\color{red}{-\,{4 \over \pi^{2}}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{2n + 1}^{2}}\,{\sin\pars{\root{\bracks{2n + 1}^{2} + 2}t} \over \root{\bracks{2n + 1}^{2} + 2}}\cos\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}x}}
\\[2mm] &\
\color{red}{+ {\root{2} \over 4}\,\sin\pars{\root{2}t}}
\end{align}